# Azure function does not scale

Tags: .net, azure, azure-functions, .net-6.0, dotnet-isolated

Today we met a problem with our azure function after redeploy a new version. We use Azure Function v4, .NET 6 and isolated process. Function is on consumption plan. Function includes about 150 http-trigger functions. Usually function scales for some instances and they work in parallel, but after todays redeploy we met situation when one instance dies and another starts, they don't work in parallel. What is the possible reason of such behavior and how to fix it?

Azure function instances

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "scale", exactly?

Comment: Adding new instances under high load